# Flutter: How to retrieve the data from firebase and show in the dropdown field

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing a Flutter application where I need to show the category field as a dropdown. I have added the category field as a dropdown in the form. I need to retrieve the data from Firebase for the category field and I have succeeded in getting the data but the problem is, it is not showing the entire data from the collection rather it is showing only one piece of data from the collection in the category dropdown field. How do I show the entire data from the collection? Please help me with your answer. Thanks!!

Here is the code for getting data from Firebase Collection

```
String _category;

  void _onCategory() async {
  _firestore.collection("categories").get().then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data()['category']);
      setState(() {
        _category = result.data()['category'] ;
      });
    });
  });
  }
```

This is the code for showing the category data in the dropdown

```
String _dropDownValue;

  Widget _categoryInput(){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      child: DropdownButton(
        hint: _dropDownValue == null
            ? Text('Category', style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),)
            : Text(
                _dropDownValue,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
        isExpanded: true,
        iconSize: 30.0,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        items: ['$_category'].map(
          (val) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: val,
              child: Text(val),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
        onChanged: (val) {
          setState(
            () {
              _dropDownValue = val;
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You just created an array with one string value and mapped it to a widget array with one value.

Comment: Could you please explain the logic through code? Because while printing the result in the console I am getting the entire list from the collection.

Comment: share your print statement

Comment: print statement after getting the data from the collection: 
I/flutter ( 9207): Necklace
I/flutter ( 9207): Diamond
I/flutter ( 9207): Rings
I/flutter ( 9207): Ear Rings

Comment: Any update Edmore!